# Text to xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, ascii

Is it possible to convert an text file to xml using xslt. I know that we can do from xml to text which i have done earlier. But we have an text file which needs to be structured as xml using xslt

Is this possible

UPDATE: (below is the text file that I need to parse as xml)

```
C0707:00addd     abcde
C0707:00tdef     ghidd 
C0715:00abcd     fghi
```

XML:

```
<b1>
<time>0707</time>
<text>addd</text>
<text2>abcde</text2>
<text>tdef</text>
<text2>ghid</text2>
</b1>

<b1>
<time>0715</time>
<text>abcd</text>
<text2>fghi</text2>
</b1>
```

Comment: I am confused by this question, ASCII is just a character set, XML usually uses the ASCII character set anyway....

Comment: So its not possible as you said.

Comment: We had an asci text file which needed to be structured as xml so i thought maybe there was a way out using xslt instead of scripting it

Comment: I didn't say that, I said your question makes no sense.

Comment: I just changed it to text file sorry for the confusion

Comment: But is it possible to convert from text to xml using xslt

Comment: No, an XSLT is an xml stylesheet

Comment: An XSLT 2.0 processor can use https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-unparsed-text to read in a text file and can then `xsl:analyze-string` and/or the `tokenize` function.

Comment: @SaggingRufus No, XML uses a subset of Unicode, not ASCII. (There are a dozen or so codepoints that cannot be natively represented.) That's notwithstanding that an XML document can have a non-Unicode encoding (with numeric character entity references used as needed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one example using [`xsl:unparsed-text`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-unparsed-text).

You don't explain the logic of how each item is broken up, so I went with a "fixed field" type format. This can easily be changed, but should be an ok example to get you started.

**Text Input** (so.txt)

```
C0707:00addd     abcde
C0707:00tdef     ghidd 
C0715:00abcd     fghi
```

**XSLT 2.0** (initial template should be set to `text2xml`)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="txt-encoding" as="xs:string" select="'iso-8859-1'"/>
  <xsl:param name="txt-uri" as="xs:string" 
    select="'file:///C:/Some/path/so.txt'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="text2xml">
    <xsl:variable name="txt" select="unparsed-text($txt-uri, $txt-encoding)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="entries" as="node()*">
      <xsl:analyze-string select="$txt" regex="\r\n?|\n">
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
          <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="^C(.{{4}}):00(.{{9}})(.*)">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
              <entry>
                <time><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/></time>
                <text><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(regex-group(2))"/></text>
                <text2><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(regex-group(3))"/></text2>
              </entry>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
          </xsl:analyze-string>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>      
    </xsl:variable>
    <results>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="$entries" group-by="time">
        <b1>
          <xsl:copy-of 
            select="current-group()[1]/time,current-group()/*[not(self::time)]"/>
        </b1>
      </xsl:for-each-group>      
    </results>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<results>
   <b1>
      <time>0707</time>
      <text>addd</text>
      <text2>abcde</text2>
      <text>tdef</text>
      <text2>ghidd</text2>
   </b1>
   <b1>
      <time>0715</time>
      <text>abcd</text>
      <text2>fghi</text2>
   </b1>
</results>
```

Comment: when i'm running your example in visual studio to understand the code, I get this error: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.  Do you have any clue

Comment: @user726720 - Is that error against the XSLT? It sounds more like you're trying to use the text file as input to the XSLT which isn't going to work. (That's why you need to specify an initial template; there is no actual input.) Also, what processor are you using in Visual Studio? You're going to need a 2.0 processor.

Comment: sorry i'm just new to the 2.0 thing. Can you suggest an editor for it. Probably the Visual studio seems like supporting the 1.0 only

Comment: I have tried oxygen editor. The result is empty. If i comment a part of xsl and just put in unparsed-text. I get the text file as output meaning the 2.0 on the oxygen editor is working. But with ur code the result is empty,  except for the xml header that is displayed. Can u help me further on this

Comment: @user726720 - I also use oXygen. What are you using for an input file? A super easy way to run the transformation in oXygen is to add `match="/"` to the xsl:template and use the XSLT file itself as the input. Be sure the path and encoding in the xsl:params are correct.

Comment: I have done the match="/" and given the xsl as it's input. It gives me the full text file as output.. Which means I'm doing the right thing. But when I put your code above back remove the match="/". I get no output.

Comment: @user726720 - I updated my answer to include the match. If you copy that XSLT exactly, update the path/file name of your text file and update the encoding (if different), it will work. Is your text file different than your example?

Comment: brilliant. I can't thank you enough for your efforts., but atleast I can try: THANK YOU !. This would help me understand how to do the transformation, and then apply this understanding to the real scenario. Thank you once again. It's working.

Comment: @DanielHaley Sir, I am taking help from u r nice suggestion, plus one.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's possible to convert arbitrary text file into XML file. You will need an XSLT 2.0 or later processor.

You need to use the `unparsed-text` functions that are available in your XSLT parser. These allow you to read in a file which is essentially a string result. From there you have several options for parsing the string.

This question addresses converting HL7 text file to XML: [Converting and HL7 segment to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843230/converting-and-hl7-segment-to-xml). The example converts a character-separated text file to an XML file, using `tokenize()` to do the rough parsing.

I've used a number of variations on this them, such as using `tokenize()` to break up lines or paragraphs, regular expressions to break out parts of strings, etc. In general, it isn't worth it for general text parsing because the parsing time is orders of magnitude slower than even a shell script. You might consider pre-processing your text file into something that XSLT could find more palatable.

Comment: `unparsed-text()` requires XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Your linked question has nothing to do with converting text to XML.

Comment: do you have any idea how to parse the text to xml. I have edited my question to give a sample text file